# "Вышла замуж за мисс"

Tags: семантика

> Навратилова вышла замуж за "мисс СССР"-1990

(Из газет).

Понимаю, что тема скандальная, но спрашиваю не "клубнички" ради. Меня интересует исключительно лингвистическая составляющая. С чего они взяли, что она "вышла замуж", а не "женилась"/"взяла в жены"?

*Я понимаю ситуацию однозначно. на женщинах женятся, замуж выходят за мужчин. 
Это, кстати,и подтверждается и менталитетом представителей полузапрещенных ныне ЛГБТ-сообществ. Такие пары обычно позиционируют себя как "две жены".*

Я чего-то недопонимаю?

Answer (score 2):

Посмотреть на это можно любым из двух способов: "женщины только выходят замуж" (лирическая героиня это и сделала) или "на женщинах можно только жениться" (на упомянутой в качестве дополнения "женились"). Второй вариант создал бы грамматическую напряжённость: слова "женилась" никто до того не употреблял (его не было в языке прессы); так мог рассудить и корректор. Поэтому выбран был первый вариант, который не так режет слух. Проще было сказать, что они "сочетались браком".

Comment: >только выходят замуж   
  
С чего бы? давайте посмотрим в корень. Что такой "выйти замуж"? приобрести мужа. Замужняя - та, у которой есть муж... Ну никак не та, которая "стала чьей-то женой" - это сложновато будет да и не соответствует правилам словообразования. Аналогично "женат" - тот, у кого есть жена. А нет то, кто "чей-то муж". Т.е. в данном случае - без всякого на то её согласия - партнершу Навратиловой назвали "мужем". А почему не наоборот? Последнее кстати, можно было бы хоть как-то обосновать... Марта в этой паре и старше, и "больше", и "сильнее". Хотя для меня звучит не менее дико.

Comment: Для редкого (если не первого) случая употребления в нашей прессе было выбрано традиционное, устойчивое выражение: вступая в брак, женщина "выходит замуж". Как внутри той социальной группы называют роли супругов, не могло бы повлиять на естественность этого высказывания. Для всех за пределами этой группы "за кого вышла, тот и муж - раз уж спрашиваете, но вышла за женщину, видать, и такое бывает."

Comment: Никто из носителей языка не стал бы по этому поводу разбирать слова на корни и приписывать новый род глаголам, кроме как с намерением поиздеваться: примерно так и шутили о "замужестве" Элтона Джона. Если "выйти замуж" противоречит этимологии, то вряд ли нужно обращаться ко второму варианту - он воспринимается гораздо более странно; можно всегда обойти такие выражения (супруги они, и всё тут).

Comment: >Для редкого (если не первого) случая употребления в нашей прессе 
  
Во-первых это далеко не так, а во-вторых, Вы не ответили по сути.
Выбирать можно один вариант из двух возможных, а не один невозможный, из одного возможного. Покажите, что семантика морфа "муж" (вышла "замуж") понимает объявленное вами прочтение "женат" - и я сразу соглашусь. Пока же не вижу причин.  
  
Кстати, очень многие комментаторы этой новости отметили диссонанс смысла и средств его выражения. Правда там намеки были совершенно неуместны для сито лингвистического исследования.